# Mapping one key to multiple commands in vim

Tags: vim

I understand that in order to execute multiple command in one line, for example save and execute `pdflatex`, I can do the following.

```
:w | !pdflatex %:t
```

Note that the `%:t`  gives you the current file name (without path). This code works fine in Vim. Now, if I want to map the whole thing above to, say ctrl+shift+F6, I'd like to be able to do the following

```
:nnoremap <C-S-F6> :w | !pdflatex %:t<CR>
```

But this doesn't work, and gives me the following error.

```
:!pdflatex paper.tex<CR>
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `pdflatex paper.tex<CR>'
```

Does this mean that I can't map ctrl+shift+F6 to the desired function, save and execute `pdflatex`? What can I do to get around this?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Assuming `<C-S-F6>` actually works (it probably won't in CLI Vim), you must escape the bar or use `<bar>` instead:

```
:nnoremap <C-S-F6> :up \| !pdflatex %:t<CR>
:nnoremap <C-S-F6> :up <bar> !pdflatex %:t<CR>
```

See `:help map_bar`.

Comment: OMG how did you know that!? Thank you very much! The `<C-S-F6>` does indeed work. I don't know what CLI Vim is.

Comment: Command Line Interface Vim, as opposed to GUI Vim. I know that because I encountered the same problem, found the answer in Vim's documentation and didn't forgot about it.

Comment: I didn't know that I had to escape that bar; thanks a lot, it saved me some hours of research