# How to combine a few commands in one shortcut in vim/neovim?

Tags: vim, shortcut, neovim

I try to create a shortcut in my Neovim config:

```
map <F3> :ALEFix<CR> :update<CR>
```

or

```
map<F3> :ALEFix<bar> :update<CR>
```

but when I press `F3` command, the shortcuts are not executed at the same time. By first press goes `ALEFix` and by second `update`. How can I create shortcut which will run `ALEFix` and `update` one after another by one press?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mapping one key to multiple commands in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23204110/mapping-one-key-to-multiple-commands-in-vim)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+map+multiple+commands

Comment: @phd <bar> are not working to me too, i dont know why

Comment: Does `\|` work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249275/vim-multiple-commands-on-same-line

Comment: `\|` doesn't work if `b` is in `cpoptions`. `^V|` should always work (see `:help map-bar`). But the cleanest solution is probably just to create a function that does both things, then map the `<F3>` to that function.

Answer (score 2):

Check Neovim [`vim.keymap.set()`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/lua.html#vim.keymap.set())

```
vim.keymap.set("n","<F3>",function ()
    vim.cmd.ALEFix() --assuming a prebuilt cmd
    vim.cmd.update() -- will need to route to your actual cmd
end)
```

This is the format you're looking for.

For example in my lua file:

```
vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>te",function ()
    vim.cmd.tabnew()
    vim.cmd.terminal()
end)
```

Which allow me to hit  + t + e to open a new tab and terminal.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34489705)